# Scroll view move to top on scrolling android

Tags: android, view, scrollview

I am working on a project, in which I have a `list of items`, I have a `banner on top` and list of items in `ScrollView` below this banner, I want when a scroll up, my `ScrollView` move up and overlaps the banner and when I scroll down scroll view come back to the first Position.

Comment: u can take a look at [this `SO Thread`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568087/parallax-header-effect-with-recyclerview/26595183#26595183)

Comment: Please post your XML and make sure every time you ask a question here you have some research and code to show peoples here.thanks