# Add Footer to bottom of grid view (below all rows) in android

Tags: android, xml, listview, gridview

I have a gridView set up in android that I am using to display Videos along with 2 different lines of text, which is all going smoothly and running fine. However when I went to add the footer such as I had done with ListViews, it doesn't appear to be an option. I have found other results on StackOverflow but they all end in the same result with the footer always being on the screen such as the footer in the Instagram app. I need a solution that will display below all of the rows such as 
`ListView.addFooter(view_footer)` would offer, in the sense of the location. I already have my footer's XML that I have used in my other activities.

How do I add an XML view below the rows in a gridView?

**EDIT 01/05/14 3:28PM**

I had an idea that if i set up another custom row, and another custom adapter, that i could add my footer in that type of way, but I don't think there can be 2 adapters.

Comment: You cannot add a Header/Footer to a `GridView` as you saw there are no methods for it. you might be able to find a third party library that does it but nothing in the Android SDK lets you do this to a gridview

Comment: Is there a workaround that you have found? preferably without 3rd party libraries. I've been attempting different solutions with no luck

Comment: No I used a third party library then gave up on it because it was not worth it. You cold try using `RecyclerView` and implementing something similar to a question I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568087/parallax-header-effect-with-recyclerview

Comment: Have you checked out http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java
Basic idea is to trick getCount(), and give it +1*columns. And then when that getView is called give the header instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790215/can-a-gridview-have-a-footer-and-header-just-like-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a third Party Library it can be easily done using this [Github Project](https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter)

To get it running in your project, start by importing it into your
**build.gradle** by adding this line:

```
compile 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.9'
```

into your `dependencies`

Secondly go to your **XML** where you have your `<GridView>` and substitute it for `<in.srain.cube.views.GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter>`

Next go to your .java class where your grid view is set up and replace This

```
GridView gridView;
```

With this

```
GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter gridView;
```

And replace this line:

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.theGrid);
```

with this

```
gridView = (GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) findViewById(R.id.theGrid);
```

.

**Finally** The most important part add your header or footer using the following:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null);
gridView.addFooterView(footer);
```

***BELOW*** THIS `gridView = (GridViewWithHeaderAndFooter) findViewById(R.id.theGrid);`

AND
***ABOVE*** THIS `gridView.setAdapter(grisViewCustomeAdapter);`