# Create a ListView like view in a ScrollView Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

So I did some research and testing of using a listview in a scrollview, and as a lot of people may know this is supposedly bad to do, since they both scroll. It also means I can't show the complete listview as it will wrap to be smaller.

I have seen places which re change the height of the listview to fix this problem but again most people say that it isn't preferred.

What I would like to know though is what is the preferred way of making a nonscrollable listview like view? Basically I want the exact same as the listview but obviously non scrolled and the height based on its contents. I would prefer to work with the layout in as much XML as possible, and I would like to be able to send my array list to it to view on screen. Unfortunately either my search skills are quite dull, as I haven't been able to find anywhere that really explains the preferred method so I thought I would ask here.

Thanks for your help.

<>Clarification Information
I thought I would put this here in case it will help, first off I basically want to show an image, with a list of comments (each one has an author and a text) below it, the comments themselves are obtained from an array and can change. I want the whole page to be scrollable though so I can either view more comments or go back up to the image.

Comment: You could make a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) (it is a newer alternative to the ListView) with an adapter which handles multiple item types. Take a look at [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)). Actually let me write this as an answer with some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and an adapter supporting [multiple item types](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) you could make a list which shows an image on top and several comments below it. Generally you'd have to check what item corresponds to each position - in your case on position 0 you have an image and in every other position you'd have a comment. Then in your adapter's [onCreateViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) and [onBindViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) you would check the item type and handle them differently.

You could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type/26245463#26245463) for a short example.
Let me know if you'd need any other details and/ or sample codes to get the idea. :)

Comment: I would go for this solution as well. Along the lines of this suggestion is the old listview's headerview, which can be applied in the recyclerview. More on this [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448717/android-5-0-add-header-footer-to-a-recyclerview).