# Material Design Navigation Adapter footer / header (How add footer ?)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I have a problem, I want put a footer in my navigation left.

I have a header that depends of code, but I don't know how I can add a footer, I tried all stuff, but not work any :

I read this post : [Android 5.0 - Add header/footer to a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448717/android-5-0-add-header-footer-to-a-recyclerview) , but my code is so diferent.

Thanks.

I put my code XML and java :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;  // Declaring Variable to Understand which View is being worked on
    // IF the viaew under inflation and population is header or Item
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    private String mNavTitles[]; // String Array to store the passed titles Value from MainActivity.java
    private int mIcons[];       // Int Array to store the passed icons resource value from MainActivity.java

    private String name;        //String Resource for header View Name
    private int profile;        //int Resource for header view profile picture
    private String email;       //String Resource for header view email
    Context context;


    // Creating a ViewHolder which extends the RecyclerView View Holder
    // ViewHolder are used to to store the inflated views in order to recycle them

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        int Holderid;

        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageView profile;
        TextView Name;
        TextView email;
        Context contxt;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView,int ViewType,Context c) {                 // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
            super(itemView);
            contxt = c;
            itemView.setClickable(true);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            // Here we set the appropriate view in accordance with the the view type as passed when the holder object is created

            if(ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText); // Creating TextView object with the id of textView from item_row.xml
                imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);// Creating ImageView object with the id of ImageView from item_row.xml
                Holderid = 1;                                               // setting holder id as 1 as the object being populated are of type item row
            }
            else{


                Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);         // Creating Text View object from header.xml for name
                email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);       // Creating Text View object from header.xml for email
                profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleView);// Creating Image view object from header.xml for profile pic
                Holderid = 0;                                                // Setting holder id = 0 as the object being populated are of type header view
            }



        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(contxt,"The Item Clicked is: "+getPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }



    MyAdapter(String Titles[], int Icons[], String Name, String Email, int Profile, Context passedContext){ // MyAdapter Constructor with titles and icons parameter
        // titles, icons, name, email, profile pic are passed from the main activity as we
        mNavTitles = Titles;                //have seen earlier
        mIcons = Icons;
        name = Name;
        email = Email;
        profile = Profile;                     //here we assign those passed values to the values we declared here
        this.context = passedContext;

        //in adapter



    }



    //Below first we ovverride the method onCreateViewHolder which is called when the ViewHolder is
    //Created, In this method we inflate the item_row.xml layout if the viewType is Type_ITEM or else we inflate header.xml
    // if the viewType is TYPE_HEADER
    // and pass it to the view holder

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

            ViewHolder vhItem = new ViewHolder(v,viewType,context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

            return vhItem; // Returning the created object

            //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder

        } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

            ViewHolder vhHeader = new ViewHolder(v,viewType,context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

            return vhHeader; //returning the object created


        }
        return null;

    }

    //Next we override a method which is called when the item in a row is needed to be displayed, here the int position
    // Tells us item at which position is being constructed to be displayed and the holder id of the holder object tell us
    // which view type is being created 1 for item row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder.Holderid ==1) {                              // as the list view is going to be called after the header view so we decrement the
            // position by 1 and pass it to the holder while setting the text and image
            holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position - 1]); // Setting the Text with the array of our Titles
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position -1]);// Settimg the image with array of our icons
        }
        else{

            holder.profile.setImageResource(profile);           // Similarly we set the resources for header view
            holder.Name.setText(name);
            holder.email.setText(email);
        }
    }

    // This method returns the number of items present in the list
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNavTitles.length+1; // the number of items in the list will be +1 the titles including the header view.
    }


    // Witht the following method we check what type of view is being passed
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

}
```

My header.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.onpocket.alcover.Fragment_0_6"
    >

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="178dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/contenedor_img_2_1_6_3"
            android:id="@+id/l1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.3" >

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/barra_lateral_img_0_1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                    android:id="@+id/circleView"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:background="#af000000"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:id="@+id/l3"
                android:focusable="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:text="text"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:id="@+id/name"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="text"
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>


    <!--
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="178dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@drawable/contenedor_img_2_1_6_3" android:scaleType="centerCrop">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@color/opacity"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:text="Akash Bangad"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"


                />

    &lt;!&ndash;        android:background="#7f000000"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"&ndash;&gt;

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="inicio_texto_empresa"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
               />
        </LinearLayout>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/barra_lateral_img_0_1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:id="@+id/circleView"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>-->
```

Main Activity (How To call)

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES, ICONS, NAME, EMAIL, PROFILE, this);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);      




  mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());


                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }
        });

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I don't know how I can add a footer

you can do the same thing you did for the `HeaderView`. Treat the footer as one of the items of RecyclerView:

Your `getItemCount` will returns

```
   @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNavTitles.length+2; 
    }
```

and you will have a method call `isPositionFooter`

```
   private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == getItemCount() - 1;
   }
```

you would change `getItemViewType` accordingly to return the footer type:

```
 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position)) {
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        } else if (isPositionFooter(position)) {
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        }
        return TYPE_ITEM;
 }
```

Comment: Hi @BlackBelt, isPositionFooter  how I can declare ?

Comment: copy/past it in your adapter ?

Comment: How I can adjust to bottom  footer ? I have only 3 ítems, and footer is "top"