# Scroll nestedscrollview to end before child recyclerview scrolls

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, nestedscrollview

here is my `layout`

```
________________  ___   
|              |   ||
| Linear       |   ||
| Layout       |   ||
|              |   || nested scroll view
|______________|   ||
||            ||   ||
||            ||   ||
||   Child    ||  _||
||Recyclerview||
||____________||
|______________|      -end
```

how do I make the parent `LinearLayout` to scroll first and when it's reached the end the child recyclerview should scroll.

By default first the child `RecyclerView` scrolls to end before the parent starts to scroll.

Comment: why not [click me, see: Flexible space](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-scrolling)  ... there is a widget for this in [design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should work with the concept of Header on a RecyclerView. Take a look at this post: [Android 5.0 - Add header/footer to a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448717/android-5-0-add-header-footer-to-a-recyclerview)