# How to create a title row in a listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in android with several columns, and for each column I want to set a separate title, as shown in this example below (I mean the fields 'Name and Number', 'SMS, 'Phone'):

[image]

(The image is just to explain what I want; in my layout there are more columns which are not as self-explaining as in the example).

Is there a good way to do that? Als, is it possible that this title row can be visible at all time, even when I have many many rows and scroll down?

Comment: why don't you create this using linear layout and just place listview below it

Comment: Do it using ListViewHeader instead of adding any extra layout

Comment: Yes good idea Vivek...

Comment: Try using RecyclerView. ListView is not recommended anymore to show a list in Android. Here's how you can achieve your goal by setting a header in your list. This is a example of how you add a footer in your RecyclerView. But anyway, adding a footer is almost the same thing. You just need to implement your own logic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448717/android-5-0-add-header-footer-to-a-recyclerview/31154402#31154402

Comment: Replacing my working list view with something else will take me at LEAST a week to do...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a fixed header item in the list that doesn't scroll with the other items, use ListView's [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()) to indicate which view(s) should stick to the top.

If you just want the first item to be different than the others, you'll have to code your ListAdapter to have two types of views, one for the header, and another for the rest.  This involves

- Making [getViewTypeCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()) return 2 to say it can make two different kinds of views.
- Making [getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) return 0 or 1 to say which type of view will be generated for the given position in the list.
- Making [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) return the correct view object for the given position in the list.

Presumably you'd want position 0 to be the header view and all other positions to be data.