# How to add multiple Recycleviews / GridViews in one activity?

Tags: android

How to add multiple Recycleviews / GridViews in one activity?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) library for a top part.

If you don't want to create a custom multi types adapter, using [NestedScrollView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) you can put as many recycler views as you wish. Just set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use multiple `GridView` or `RecyclerView` to achieve the behaviour you want in you application. In case of having multiple lists (multiple data types in your second picture) you can take a look at this [github project](https://github.com/comeondude/dynamic-recyclerview).

The code explanation is here at the [wiki attached with this project](https://github.com/comeondude/dynamic-recyclerview/wiki).

So you can achieve both behaviours (i.e. your first and second screen easily) after you understand how you can easily show multiple lists or data types in a single `RecyclerView`.

**Hint:** In your first screen, the top can easily be added as the header of the `RecyclerView`.

To see how to add headers/footers in your `RecyclerView` you can [check the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154402/3145960).