# Nested ArrayList while creating RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an android application where i am using a RecyclerView to display a list of items.I am getting the list from server as json.So my problem is within this list i am getting another list as item.That is if my main arraylist contain title and materials, the material is another arraylist.So can you please suggest a solution to display a list within recyclerview.

The code below is my adapter

```
public class CurriculumAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Curriculum> mArrayListCurriculum;

    public CurriculumAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Curriculum> mArrayListCurriculum) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mArrayListCurriculum = mArrayListCurriculum;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_key_features, parent,false);
        return new KeyFeatureViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof KeyFeatureViewHolder) {
            ((KeyFeatureViewHolder) holder).mTextViewFeatureTitle.setText(mArrayListCurriculum.get(position).getTitle());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mArrayListCurriculum == null ? 0 : mArrayListCurriculum.size();
    }

    public static class KeyFeatureViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mTextViewFeatureTitle;

        public KeyFeatureViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextViewFeatureTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtFeature);
        }
    }
}
```

The code below is my fragment with dummy arraylist data

```
public class CourseCurriculumFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentInterface mFragmentInterface;
    private ArrayList<Curriculum> mArrayListCurriculum;
    private ArrayList<Material> mArrayListMaterial;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewCurriculum;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private CurriculumAdapter mCurriculumAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course_curriculum, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        initView(view);
    }

    private void initView(View view) {
        mArrayListMaterial = new ArrayList<>();
        mArrayListCurriculum = new ArrayList<>();
        populateMaterials();
        populateKeyFeatures();

        mRecyclerViewCurriculum = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCurriculum);
        mCurriculumAdapter = new CurriculumAdapter(getActivity(), mArrayListCurriculum);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerViewCurriculum.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerViewCurriculum.setAdapter(mCurriculumAdapter);
        mRecyclerViewCurriculum.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }

    private void populateMaterials() {
        mArrayListMaterial.add(new Material("12:00","pdf","","Sample Text","0"));
        mArrayListMaterial.add(new Material("12:00","pdf","","Sample Text","0"));
    }

    private void populateKeyFeatures() {
        mArrayListCurriculum.add(new Curriculum("UNIT 1",mArrayListMaterial));
        mArrayListCurriculum.add(new Curriculum("UNIT 2",mArrayListMaterial));
        mArrayListCurriculum.add(new Curriculum("UNIT 3",mArrayListMaterial));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the reply.But what i have done is I have used a nested recycler view concept to achieve this.That is i have used a recyclerview and inside the adapter of that recyclerview i have added another recyclewrview to display the Material Arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

A `bind` method in a holder is a good way to pass data to it.

In your case this `bind` method should take in a `Curriculum` and a `Material` object as parameters.

Inside the `onBindViewHolder` method of the adapter, instead of reaching into the variables of the holder, you should call this `bind` method.

In the implementation of the method inside the you `KeyFeatureViewHolder` class you should use these passed parameters and display them in the appropriate UI elements.

Lastly, to get the `Material` object data into adapter, add `ArrayList<Material>` as a constructor parameter just like you did with `Curriculum`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Use `RecyclerView` with header, `title` as header and `materials` as items of that header. Look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530685/is-there-an-addheaderview-equivalent-for-recyclerview).

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You need to design a custom list for yourself. For example take an object like this.

```
public class ListItem {
    public curriculumName = null;
    public materialName = null;
}
```

Now populate this list after you parse the JSON string. Get your first `Curriculum` and populate the object like this

```
private ArrayList<ListItem> mListItemArray = new ArrayList<ListItem> ();

for(curriculum : mArrayListCurriculum) {

    ListItem mListItemHead = new ListItem();    
    mListItemHead.curriculumName = curriculum.getName();

    // Set the header here
    mListItemArray.add(mListItemHead);

    for(material : curriculum.getMaterials()){
        ListItem mListItem = new ListItem();
        mListItem.materialName = material.getName();

        // Add materials here
        mListItemArray.add(mListItem);
    }
}
```

Now, you've a list with headers and materials. When the `materialName` in your `mListItemArray` is null, it identifies that this is a header and vice versa.

Now the trick is to modify your adapter of your `RecyclerView` so that you can bind proper view to your items in your list.

You can find an indication from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154402/3145960) on how you can achieve this desired behaviour.

Basically, the idea is to modify your `getItemViewType` to pass the proper view in your `onBindViewHolder`. Your `getItemViewType` might look like this.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mListItemArray.get(position).curriculumName != null) {
        // This is where we'll add header.
        return HEADER_VIEW;
    }

    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply