# Java conditional statement not working as expected

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to override `getItemViewType` and return a different view type for my footer, but integer comparison is failing within the function:

[image]

This image shows a debug session where the input `position` is 21 and the the private List `mValues` has a size of 21, however when I pushed "step over" the conditional code is skipped.

If both integers are equal, why does `position == mValues.size()` return false?

I cleaned and rebuilt my project before running.

UPDATE:

It works when the integers are hardcoded:

[image]

but not when I use the input parameter:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I added a Log statement as the first line of the function

```
Log.e("MYAPP", "position: " + position + ", evaluates: " + (position == 21));
```

and in my monitor I see: `position: 21, evaluates: true`

However, my breakpoint at `return FOOTER_VIEW;` is never called and none of the functions related to the footer view are ever called.

UPDATE:

Heres the full Adaptor: https://gist.github.com/fergusom/79c6d5d9b1fd5e8348949d114a0159d5

Note that I updated the code to compute a `boolean` first, but it still fails even though the `boolean` prints out `true` in the logs

Comment: What type is mValues (runtime type)? Did you try stepping into mValues.size()? Can you verify that it returns 21?

Comment: If I replace `mValues.size()` with 21, it still fails, added a picture that shows this

Comment: Don't trust the debugger! Put logs statements inside and outside the `if`.

Comment: The debugger may highlight the wrong line because of code optimizations.

Comment: ok but if I put my breakpoint `return FOOTER_VIEW`, it never gets triggered, even though `position` clearly reaches 21

Comment: what is mValues actually?

Comment: Nothing beats a `log.d`. Also, make sure you clean the project when you start seeing weird stuff happening, especially with instant run on.

Comment: I already cleaned it, in the OP. just added a log but it still implies the conditional statement is failing somehow

Comment: @Shahid, I replaced `mValues` with a hard coded 21

Comment: Are you returning 2 from `getViewTypeCount` method?

Comment: `getViewTypeCount` isn't a function. for `getItemViewType` I only return 1 or call the super function

Comment: Try to override `getViewTypeCount` method and return 2 from it.

Comment: put both `position` and `mValue.size()` in the log

Comment: @mbmc I replaced `mValue.size()` with a hardcoded 21 and it still fails

Comment: @KNeerajLal I'm using a `RecyclerView.Adapter`. that function isn't available

Comment: have you tried restarting your ide? ;)

Comment: My bad, I thought it was a `ListView`. :)

Comment: are you sure the method is actually called? if you put a log statement or breakpoint on entry to the method, do you see the method itself being called?

Comment: @KevinHooke yes, that is what the pictures are all showing

Comment: Can you post the whole adapter code?

Comment: @Shahid just restarted, still the same problem.

Comment: @KNeerajLal just posted the full adaptor in the last update

Comment: @Cbas why the try catch in bindViewholder

Comment: @ColdFire idk I got that code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448717/android-5-0-add-header-footer-to-a-recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted my phone and it started working...

Comment: that was entertaining :)

Answer (score 1):

Give the jvm no chance:

```
if(new Integer(position).equals(new Integer(mValues.size()))
```

If the Integer constructor fails you'll know what the values were in the exception

Comment: I tried going one step further and creating a `boolean` to use in the conditional and it still failed even when the `boolean` prints out `true` in a log. check out the full gist in the last update

Comment: Wait what? You printed a boolean variable, gives you true and it doesn't goes in the if statement?

Comment: yes. seems to have been a glitch on my device. I restarted my phone and its working now