# How to hide RecyclerView footer while list is empty?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to hide RecyclerView footer while list is empty and show it again when list has some items?

I implemented footer according to this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154402)

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: @NJ i tried to show and hide footer directly in the Footer ViewHolder's constructor by checking list's size, it didn't work

Comment: Obviously `getItemCount()` would be better place ...

Comment: why don't you simply hide your RecyclerView instead, if there is no data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did check it in getItemCount

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (list.isEmpty()) return 0;
    else return list.size() + 1;
}
```