# Android - OnLoadMore in RecyclerView with wrap_content height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have `RecyclerView` which its height is set to `wrap_content`. Now I need to implement `OnLoadMore` to it but there is a problem.
I used,

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
```

But it doesn't get invoked because my `RecyclerView` doesn't scroll. Its height is `wrap_content`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_rtl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tool_bar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.yarima.msn.Activities.ProfileActivity">

            <FrameLayout
                 android:id="@+id/FRAGMENT_PLACEHOLDER"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="@color/white">

                 <!-- Some Content That I want to scroll with recyclerview -->
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                 android:id="@+id/recyclerview_posts"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:scrollbars="vertical"
                 android:bellow="@id/FRAGMENT_PLACEHOLDER"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I need to use another approach for loading more pages to `RecyclerView`.
I think the best way to do this, is calling `onLoadMore` event when the last item of `RecyclerView` become visible. I already tried to do this from `onBindViewHolder` method in adapter, but all pages loaded altogether.

```
if(getItemCount()-position == 1 && onLoadMoreListener != null){
    if (recyclerView != null) {
        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            loading = true;
            onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the alternative way to implement `onLoadMore` without using scroll events?

**Update:**

The `RecyclerView` works perfectly with `android:layout_height:"wrap_content"` and my `ScrollView` scrolls smoothly.

**Update 2:**

My problem is when your `RecyclerView` height is `wrap_content`, scroll events of `RecyclerView` cannot be invoked. So I need an alternative way to find out when my `RecyclerView` reaches to end of its list and implement `OnLoadMore` event that way.

**Update 3**

I simplified xml before I wrote it in question... In real xml, there is `ViewPager` instead of the `RecyclerView`. And I have 4 tabs in that `ViewPager` that each tab contains a `RecyclerView` with different contents.

Above of this `ViewPager` I have some information about user and I want to scroll all of them together. So I put this header and `ViewPager` in a `ScrollView` and set the height of `RecyclerView` to `wrap_content`.

You can take a look at profile page of instagram. I want to this page works like that.

It's not possible to show this information in header of `RecyclerView` because in this way, I should add this information in each `RecyclerView` in every tabs.

Comment: what is support library android version you are using ?

Comment: @Ironman 24.2.1

Comment: Why do you need the `RecyclerView` height to be `wrap_content` anyway?

Comment: @ReazMurshed: I simplified xml before I wrote it in question... In real xml, there is `ViewPager` instead of the `RecyclerView`. And I have 4 tabs in that `ViewPager` that each tab contains a `RecyclerView` with different contents. above of this `ViewPager` I have some information about user and I want to all this page scroll togather so I put this header and `ViewPager` in a `ScrollView` and set the height of `RecyclerView` to `wrap_content`... You can take a look at profile page of instagram. I want to this page works like that.

Comment: Set the information about user as a header of the `RecyclerView`. Simpler approach. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31154402/3145960

Comment: @ReazMurshed It's not possible because this `RecyclerView` and 3 others are in a `ViewPager`. Each `RecyclerView` in a tab of `ViewPager`. So if I want to show this information in header of `RecyclerView`, I should add it in every `RecyclerView`s in different pages of `ViewPager`.

Comment: Hmm... Now I get it. I'll get an answer to your question tonight I hope. Please have patience.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Ok... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

Could look for scroll events in scrollview

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int)

Comment: I already set this to false, becuase if It be true, recyclerview doesn't scroll smoothly....

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your `ViewPager` and your `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`. The final xml should look like this.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ViewPager/>
    <RecyclerView/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And set the height of your `RecyclerView` to `match_parent`.

You'll face another problem here. The page will automatically scroll to bottom when the `RecyclerView` will be loaded. But there's a solution to it too.

Adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the child layout in `NestedScrollView` which will prevent the automatic scrolling to the bottom.

If the above doesn't work, try setting `nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);` from your code after the `RecyclerView` is loaded with items.