# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView inside SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't scroll smoothly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

Here's my layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/noob_button"
                android:text="haha" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/noob_button"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This is all inside `RelativeLayout`.

I have set `recyclerview.setNestedScrol..(false);`

It still hangs and if I set fixed height of the `RecyclerView` it doesn't hang. It scrolls but the scroll is not smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually need a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`. As far as I have understood your question, you need a `Button` and a `RecyclerView` under the button. So you might consider adding the `Button` as the header of the `RecyclerView` which is neater implementation.

If you are thinking of adding a header in your `RecyclerView` please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154402/3145960) on how this can be achieved.

I have explained how a footer can be added. The same rule applies for adding a header view as well. Please let me know if you have any further questions regarding this.

Comment: If i put it as a header it will be occupying the first row of the recyclerview and i won't be able to manage the data coming from api in recyclerview

Comment: Surely you can manage the data received from your API. You need to handle the login inside your `onBindViewHolder`. It would be great if you could help us to understand the scenario that you are having. So that we could help more specifically.

Comment: The recyclerview is being filled from data which i get from api so if i put a header that means the header will occupy the first row of the recyclerview so the data on the first position of the json array will be beneath of the header.

Comment: The means header will overlap the first data, if i set data from second position then on every api call the header will repeat.  I just wanted the view(Textview, viewpager) to be above the recyclerview and don't have any relation with the recycler but scrolls when we scroll recyclerview so i used the nestedcrollview but it causes lags.  I am thinking to set the appropriate data in the api i.e the required data on first position.

Comment: Nope. Neither the header will repeat each time you call the API not it will overlap the first data. I think you have misunderstood the idea of having a header of a `RecyclerView`. The header can have a custom layout as well. Please follow the implementation of adding a header in you `RecyclerView` first. You will have the idea.