# Nestedscrollview not working well

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

in my app i have to put recyclerview below some information and some photos and i'm testing the activity but it doesn't work very well and i don't know why !

any one can help me with that, i just need to scroll all things together like one thing . i tried many solutions but no thing solute my issue

[here is a video for my issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HqWRyPA4zA)

**xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinate_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:dividerPadding="8dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:showDividers="end">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                        android:text="Upload Item"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_save"
                        style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/done"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/coordinate_layout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/relative1">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/shoes"
                        android:id="@+id/profile_imagee" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/shoes"
                        android:id="@+id/profile_imagee1"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_imagee" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/shoes"
                        android:id="@+id/profile_imagee2"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_imagee1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="change profile"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_imagee2"/>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/relative1">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_profile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

                    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 SwipeRefreshLayout in the same xml file? Try getting rid of one...

Comment: no thing happened

Comment: You might just consider adding a header in your `RecyclerView` instead of having them altogether inside a `NestedRecyclerView`. [Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154402/3145960) you can add a custom layout as a header of your `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

In recyclerview add an attribute 
nestedScrollingEnabled to false in xml it will solve your problem