# Buttons between Listviews disappear

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I try to create a layout which should look like this:

- Listview
- ImageButton
- Listview
- ImageButton
- Listview
- ImageButton
- ....

So that I have 5 Listviews and 5 ImageButtons in the end.

If I have just one element in each `ListView` it works fine but when I start adding more and more elements the buttons disappear behind the elements.

Now it looks like one big `ListView` instead of being separated by a `Button`.

That is the `layout.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/detailview_1_listview"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/detailview_1_button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailview_1_listview"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailview_1_button_add"
        android:id="@+id/detailview_2_listview"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/detailview_2_button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailview_2_listview"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailview_2_button_add"
        android:id="@+id/detailview_3_listview"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/detailview_3_button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailview_3_listview"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailview_3_button_add"
        android:id="@+id/detailview_4_listview"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/detailview_4_button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailview_4_listview"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailview_4_button_add"
        android:id="@+id/detailview_5_listview" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/detailview_5_button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailview_5_listview"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `list_item.xml` is

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detailview_1_imageview"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="62dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="62dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detailview_2_imageview"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="196dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="62dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="62dp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/detailview_switch_mangel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="524dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:text="Mangel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/detailview_textview_beschreibung"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="366dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="Beschreibung"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/detailview_textview_fensternummer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/detailview_switch_mangel"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/detailview_textview_beschreibung"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nummer"
        android:inputType="number" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: off course it will disappear. Your best bet is to use scrollview as a parent layout.

Comment: instead the relative layout or in the relative layout ? :)

Comment: It's due to parent layout. You are using relative layout as parent and for list view you are using wrap content so its disappearing behind layout.

Comment: @Michi use scrollview as parent layout, and give fix height to your listviews. So you will be able to see all your data.

Comment: The way you're using the ListViews defeats their purpose. Use LinearLayouts instead and add new Views dynamically.

Comment: @Michi use some constant values for height for list views so it won't change

Comment: @user1504495 i did a lot of research about this approach but i didnt find a thing about it

Comment: @Michi The reason for using ListView or RecyclerView is because it is very efficient if used correctly. However in your layout you'd lose all the benefits and they'd be more hassle than anything else. Basically to have the advantages of List/RecyclerView it needs to have any other height other than wrap_content. If you must have wrap_content you might as well use a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you add the `ImageButton` under each `ListView` as the footer of that `ListView`. In that case, the button will not hide anymore and you will get an appropriate behaviour while scrolling your list.

It is very simple to add a footer in your `ListView`. I am just sharing some code from this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265324/3145960) for convenience.

```
View footerView =  ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Please remember to add the footer view in your `ListView` before setting your adapter in your `ListView`.

There is another way to having the behaviour that you want, with using `NestedScrollView`. Here is a [nice tutorial](http://www.devexchanges.info/2017/01/populating-multiple-list-views-on.html) on how you can have multiple `RecyclerView` inside a single `NestedScrollView`.

If you are considering to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`, you might have a single `RecyclerView` and populate the items based on your need like the way suggested [here](https://github.com/masudias/dynamic-recyclerview). The idea is to have a single `RecyclerView` so that your scrolling and recycling the views can be implemented in most effective way.

Comment: You suggestion is nice until `RecyclerView`s, why it haven't any attribute footer or header

Comment: I think you have misunderstood about the different view types that I wanted to point out. I have also provided a [github link](https://github.com/masudias/dynamic-recyclerview) to explain using different view types in `RecyclerView` as well. Please have a look. However, you might also add a footer or header in a `RecyclerView`.  See this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154402/3145960).

Comment: If I do it with the footer approach I have to create one footer_layout.xml for each ListView. Did I get it right ?

Comment: Yes, you might create a separate footer for each `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ScrollView` as a parent layout. Then your `listview` won't merge with your `imageButtons`.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/detailview_1_listview"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/detailview_1_button_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detailview_1_listview"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detailview_1_button_add"
    android:id="@+id/detailview_2_listview"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/detailview_2_button_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detailview_2_listview"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detailview_2_button_add"
    android:id="@+id/detailview_3_listview"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/detailview_3_button_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detailview_3_listview"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detailview_3_button_add"
    android:id="@+id/detailview_4_listview"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/detailview_4_button_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detailview_4_listview"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detailview_4_button_add"
    android:id="@+id/detailview_5_listview"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/detailview_5_button_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/detailview_5_listview"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    />
```

Comment: listview inside a scrollview? or nested scrollview? Which one is better?

Comment: Doing so would make the ScrollView capture any scroll events and make the ListViews useless.

Comment: listview inside a scrollview, nested scrollview will make it messy. In this way scrollview will take the scroll and also listviews will have fix heights so they won't merge will each other.

Comment: By the way this design approach the OP is using is all togather wrong because it's not how it is done. Best way is to inflate layout at run time and implement a nested scroll.