# Buttons Are No Longer Clickable After I add RecyclerView to Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout

Before I added the RecyclerView to my layout, I was able to click the "TextView" (android:id="@+id/how_is_your_day_question"), which has been programmed to be able to click. After I added the RecylerView to the layout, I am no longer able to click on this TextView. I have played around with the layout and cannot seem to figure it out. Logcat says "I/Surface: opservice is null false" when I click on the TextView. As soon as I remove the RecyclerView, I can click on the TextView item again, and it behaves as expected. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE: I WAS ABLE TO RESOLVE ISSUE AFTER ADDING MARGIN_TOP TO THE RECYCLERVIEW- VERY SILLY MISTAKE. LOL**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Personal_Wall"
    tools:openDrawer="end">






    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            elevation="4dp">



            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:id="@+id/hapana_button"
                android:text="hapana_button"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_hapana_button2"/>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:fillViewport="true">




        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment-containter2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">




                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/assists_number"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="15 Assists *" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/followers_number"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="1000 Followers *" />




            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_place_holder"
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_place_holder"
                app:civ_border_color="#fff"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:civ_border_width="5dp" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/temporary_banner_personal_wall"
                android:layout_width="380dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_hapana_banner_2"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>




            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_first_name"
                android:layout_width="193dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="First"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_last_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Last"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:textColor="#000"/>

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleX="0.7"
                android:scaleY="0.7"
                android:rating="5"
                android:isIndicator="true"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="540dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_location"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_profile_location_on_black_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:text="Current Location:   City, State" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/postsomething"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="460dp"
                android:background="@color/fui_transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_posting_line"/>




            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/how_is_your_day_question"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:text="How is your day?" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/photo_with_icon_camera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_profile_camera_grey"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text= "Camera" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/photo_with_icon_video_green"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="97dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_profile_video_grey"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text= "Video" />




            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/photo_with_icon_gallery"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="173dp"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_profile_photo_grey"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text= "Photos" />



            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/edit_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
                android:background="@color/fui_transparent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit_icon_2" />






            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_profile_page"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_patent"
                android:paddingTop="560dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>




        </RelativeLayout>


        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>



    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because your recyclerview's height matches the parent, while all your other views in the same hierarchy as the recycler view have their heights set to wrap content. This would mean that the recycler view is drawing over all its siblings declared above.

I suggest you change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your RecyclerView and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, that solution results in my RecyclerView disappearing when I run the app, and my TextView is still not clickable.

Comment: Wait, I will go back to my home and paste it in my Android studio and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being addressed in an earlier answer. The `RecyclerView` is overlapping the other items and hence they are not clickable.

I would recommend getting rid of the `FrameLayout` and replace that with a `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout` so that you can position every item without overlapping each other.

The `wrap_content` is not going to work sometimes if the list is loaded after the `RecyclerView` is loaded with an empty list first.

**Update**

After changing it to the `RelativeLayout` container, looks like it is still covering up all the items that you have in your layout. I would recommend setting the following attribute in your `RecyclerView` and let me know if that solves your click problem now.

```
android:layout_below="@+id/how_is_your_day_question"
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I changed FrameLayout to RelativeLayout, and unfortunately, it results in the TextView still not being clickable.

Comment: Can you please share the updated layout that you have?

Comment: Looks like the `RecyclerView` is still overlapping all the items. Do you have a screenshot of the design so that we can understand exactly what you want?

Comment: Also, can you please check my updated answer? Thank you!

Comment: I updated my question with an image. Thank you for your solution. My TextView is now clickable but my RecycleView has disappeared.

Comment: Because your `RecyclerView` is still having the `wrap_content`. Please change it to `match_parent` back again.

Comment: IMHO, your layout is way too complicated for this design that you are trying to achieve. Looks like you could have the layout above the `RecyclerView` as a header for the `RecyclerView` and could avoid having the `NestedScrollView`. Here's how you can add a header to your `RecyclerView` just in case - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31154402/3145960

Comment: Hi, my apologies. I had the RecyclerView with match_parent, but forgot to update it on stackoverflow. I tried it with match_parent and my RecyclerView stopped appearing. I have updated the code in stackoverflow. I had to add the NestledScrollView because I was experiencing weird scrolling behavior with my RecyclerVew. It wasn't scrolling with the rest of my page so I had to add NestledScrollview. But thank you for the link. I will look at it.

Comment: In that case, I would argue that your `RecyclerView` does not have any data :D

Comment: There is data coming in. If I change to FrameLayout, the RecyclerView works with data coming in, but my TextView stops being clickable lol so weird.