# How to use a RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView such that only visible items are loaded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

The intended layout shall be a grid layout of individual items which are broken into sections by a horizontal divider and a caption. (One might thinkg of the gallery view of Google Photos.) The layout shall be scrollable as a whole. The following figure illustrates a mockup.

[image: Mockup]

On the left one can see the whole (virtual) layout. On the right, one see can see the visible view port.

At a rough glance, the current XML structure of the layout looks like that:

```
androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
  |
  +-- LinearLayout
        |
        +-- TextView     (the first caption)
        +-- androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        +-- View         (the divider)
        +-- TextView     (the second caption)
        +-- androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

The height of the `RecyclerView` is set to `wrap_content` and `setNestedScrollingEnabled( false )` is called as recommended [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37338715/2690527).

**Problem:** Although the layout works as expected, it is inefficient. The `ReyclerView` instantiates an independent object `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` for each item in the whole gallery not only for the visible items. In the example: 60 objects instead of only 26. In other words, the `ReyclerView` does not recycle anything. In addition, `onBindViewHolder` is also called 60 times during creation of the view, which means I would eventually have to load all data at once. (When the mockup icons will be replaced by true images.)

**Background:** Of course, I understand the cause of the problem. From the perspective of a `RecyclerView` everything is visible at once. The `RecyclerView` does not know that is is embedded in a `NestedScrollView` which clips away the invisible parts.

**Question:** How do I achieve the intended layout and benefit from advantages of a `RecyclerView` (recycling of views, lazy/paged loading of data)? Maybe, using `RecyclerView` is the wrong approach and I need to use something totally different.

Comment: I think you could achieve everything you want with a single `RecyclerView`. Use `getItemViewType()` to draw the captions and dividers, and `SpanSizeLookup` to make them span the full width of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

NestedScrollView draws all child elements, Thats why you lose all the advantages of using RecyclerView. If you want to improve this, you should use a Header (The TextView) and a Footer (Divider) for your recyclerView and avoid the NestedScrollView. Checkout this example [Header/Footer in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26813208/13073254)